# Chebyshev Inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, random-variables

I am reading a research paper, and the author claims to get to a desired result by making use of the Chebyshev Inequality. I can get to the desired result also with some reasoning, but I fail to understand how to use the Chebyshev Inequality to get to it.

Let $\{c_i\}_{i=1}^{i=M}$ be elements of $\mathbb{R^n}$, such that they satisfy the constraint  $\frac{1}{M}\sum_{i=1}^{i=M}||c_i||^2\leq nP$ where $P,\tilde{P}\in \mathbb{R^+},\ P<\tilde{P}$.

Given such a set $\{c_i\}_{i=1}^{i=M}$ that satisfies the constraint, I would like to count the number of elements $i$ such that $||c_i||^2 > n\tilde P$. To put it concisely I want to know #$\{i:||c_i||^2 > n\tilde P\}$. Simple reasoning shows that #$\{i:||c_i||^2> n\tilde P\}\leq M\frac{P}{\tilde P}$.

**Please share the insight to get to the result with the Chebyshev Inequality.**

My reasoning works like this: Imagine the above is not true, and then I count the number of elements with $||c_i||^2 > n \tilde P$ and the elements that $\leq n\tilde P$ and arrive at the contradiction to the above constraint.

Answer (score 1):

The reasoning is quite simple: now that I think about it.

Recall Chebyshev Inequality (or simply Markov Inequality): 
$\boldsymbol{P}(\{\omega:X(\omega)\geq\epsilon\})\leq\frac{\boldsymbol E(X)}{\epsilon}$

Let $X=||Y||^2$ so $X$ is also a RV and $X\geq0$ as needed. Let $Y\in \{c_i\}_{i=1}^{i=M}$ with uniform probability. So $\boldsymbol E(X)\leq nP$.

Now the $\boldsymbol{P}(\{\omega:X(\omega)\geq n\tilde P\})\leq\frac{\boldsymbol E(X)}{n \tilde P}$ and this is also implies from above that $\boldsymbol{P}(\{\omega:X(\omega)\geq n\tilde P\})\leq\frac{P}{\tilde P}$

But we can also interpret $\boldsymbol{P}(\{\omega:X(\omega)\geq n\tilde P\})=\frac{\#\{i:||c_i||^2>n\tilde P\}}{M}$, and thus we get $\#\{i:||c_i||^2>n\tilde P\} \leq M \frac{P}{\tilde P}$, as needed.